# Declaring any iostream related object in header throws error upon attempt to initialize

Tags: c++, iostream

I have declared both a

```
class myclass
{
private:
  stringbuf* mbuf;
  iostream* mios;
};
```

in my class .h header file. however when I try to initialize them in my constructor like so:

```
myclass::myclass()
{
  mbuf = new stringbuf();
  mios = new iostream(mbuf);

}
```

it throws an error along the lines of:

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'std::stringbuf'
```

and then of course the iostream complains about not being able to use the stringbuf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you include the appropriate headers i.e. `<sstream>` for `stringbuf` and `<iostream>` for `iostream`?

Comment: Oh my god, me over analyzing at it's best, thank you so much. I feel like a moron, though stringbuf/basic_stringbuf was declared in iostream!

Comment: @alexhairyman: This is often the case with the streams library objects. However, I find it a good practice to include all relevant headers (as sort of documentation). Also, if you later on remove the `iostream` object and your `<iostream>` include directive, you will not be surprised with strange error messages!

Comment: Or use a main .h file to include everything you need and then just include that in everything else? Same sort of thing?

Comment: @alexhairyman: Yes, using a precompiled header is a good thing to speed up compilation. However, I'd be very wary to put the whole `iostream` in that header though. More likely, would be `<sstream>`.

Comment: @alexhairyman I would not use a main .h file and include it in everything. Any time you sneeze at that file or any file it references - let's say you want to add something to a class - it will recompile every module in the project. In general it is best to explicitly include each header that is required in each TLU (.cpp file), and put as many of those in the .cpp as possible.